# How to disable Ant Junit Task from closing browser when new test starts

Tags: selenium, ant, junit, webdriver

How can i disable **Ant Junit Task** from closing my browser? My code permits to run test on one browser (in on session).

When i run from IDEA it run through 1 browser my tests but when run through Ant it closing and opening my browser each time when new test runs.

**Update:** somehow to disable teardown, my test doesn't have teardown

```
<target name="company" depends="build">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr" showoutput="true" outputtoformatters="true" haltonfailure="no"
           failureproperty="test.failed" haltonerror="no">
        <sysproperty key="webdriver.browser" value="${webdriver.browser}"/>
        <sysproperty key="project.config" value="${project.config}"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="com.tests.MainHomePage" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <test name="com.tests.company.AboutCompany" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <classpath refid="seleniumproject.classpath"/>
        <classpath refid="myWebDriver.classpath"/>
    </junit>
    <fail message="Test failure detected, check test results." if="test.failed"/>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution need to add `forkmode="once"`, it will run 1 VM for entire Junit Task

Example:

```
<junit fork="yes" forkmode="once" printsummary="withOutAndErr" showoutput="true" outputtoformatters="true" haltonfailure="no"
       failureproperty="test.failed" haltonerror="no">
```